# Smallest multiple containing only 1's and 0's

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest number that is composed of only zeros and ones and is (a)divisible by both three and five,
(b)lowest multiple of 16

My Answer for (b): Clearly the number needs to be divisible by at the least 4 2's, which means 0 has to be the Units digit, then, similarly tens digit has to be 0 too, as we would otherwise have X...10/2 = X...5 which is odd. So, it must be 10000. But I don't know how to solve (a) similarly.

I'm not too sure of the Tag for this question, so please feel free to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any multiple of 5 ends with either a 0 or a 5. Pick a 0, since 5 isn't 0 or 1. Any multiple of 3 has sum of digits as a multiple of 3. So, it must be 1110.

Answer (score 0):

Necessarily the number $N$ is of the shape $N=1a_1a_2...a_n0$ in both cases.

a)$\space N=3M\Rightarrow 1+a_1+...+a_n=3M_1$ $\Rightarrow N=1110 $

b)$\space N=1a_1a_2...a_n0\Rightarrow1a_1a_2...a_n0=10M_1\Rightarrow a_n=0\Rightarrow a_{n-1}=0$ and so on successively because being even can not finish by 1. Thus $N=10000$

Comment: How do you get from $N=1a_1 \dots a_n0$ to $1a_1 \dots a_n = 10M_1$?

Comment: It was a lapse I have corrected before read your comment. Thanks.